# analogy of SUMIFS in Excel function in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a difficulty with applying Excel SUMIFS type function in Pandas.
I have a table similar to one on picture.
I need to find Sum of each product sold each day. But I don't need it in Summary table. I need it to be written in column next to each one as shown in red column. In excel I'm using SUMIFS function. But in Pandas I can't find any analogy.
Once again, I don't need just count/or sum  as shown summary in another table. I need it be near each entry in new column. Is there any way I can do it?
P.S VERY Important thing- Writing with group by where I will need to write each condition isn't a solution. Because I want it to show next to each cell. In my data there will be thousands of entries and I don't know each entry to write =="apple", =="orange" each time. I need the same logic as in Excel.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76VX1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `groupby` and its [`transform` method.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)

Creating something that looks like your dataframe, but abbreviated:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ["22.10.2021", "22.10.2021", "22.10.2021", "22.10.2021", "23.10.2021"],
    'Product': ["apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "cherry"],
    'sold_kg': [2, 3, 1, 4, 2]})
```

Then we group by and apply the sum as transformation to the `sold_kg` column and assign the result back as a new column:

```py
df['Sold that day'] = df.groupby(['date', 'Product']).sold_kg.transform("sum")
```

[image: Sold that day column created]

In your words, we often use `groupby` to create "summaries" or aggregations. But `transform` is also useful to know since it allows us to splat the result back into the data frame it came from, just like in your example.

Comment: Good! If it's a good answer you might upvote or accept it.

Comment: upvoting isn't active for me since I'm new user. But I accepted! Thanks again!

Comment: Oh right. Yes, it's annoying how slow it is to "start" on stackoverflow, to get some reputation. :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

if we consider the image as dataframe `df`, simply do

```
>>> pd.merge( df.groupby(['Date','Product']).sum().reset_index(),df, on=['Date','Product'], how='left')
```

You will just need to rename some columns later-on, but that should do